# How to clear all subscripted variables?

Tags: clear

I have the following variable:

```
Subscript[n, 0 ] = 12 (\[Sigma] L^2)/(e h^2)
```

If I now do:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

And then call:

```
Subscript[n, 0 ]
```

I get:

```
12 (\[Sigma] L^2)/(e h^2)
```

... So apparently a variable with a subscript cannot be deleted by "clear all".

How can you do it ?

Here for testing:

```
Subscript[n, 0 ] =12 (\[Sigma] L^2)/(e h^2)
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Subscript[n, 0 ]
```

Comment: `Clear[Subscript]`. More generally, don't use subscripts at all.